# Call specific fields of nested/child form in template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have created a nested form using `forms.inlineformset_factory`. In views.py I define the parent form (`form`) and form set (`form_set`) variables. When I call the variables in the template, I am able to select specific fields of the parent (i.e. `{{ form.var1 }}` and `{{ form.var2 }}`) but I cannot do the same with the child form (i.e. `{{ form_set.var3 }}`). I have confirmed that `{{ form_set }}` works and the child field appears. How can I call specific child fields?

The end goal (and I may be approaching this the wrong way; any suggestion is appreciated) is for the user to supply any desired number nested forms to a single parent (i.e. an author can write many books) or this information can be supplied via csv upload (note `var3` is a `FileField`) which will fill out the model fields in the backend. I would like for there to be a single file upload option (`var3`) but multiple other child options as desired. For example, `var3` should always appear once but `var4`, `var5`, and `var6` can appear any number of times as a set. A csv upload would overwrite the keyed in entry. Thanks for any help in advance!

Code below:

models.py

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    var1= models.CharField(max_length=128)
    var2= models.CharField(max_length=128)


class Child(models.Model):
    var1= models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    var3 = models.FileField(upload_to='media/')
    var4 = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    var5 = models.FloatField()
    var6 = models.FloatField()
```

forms.py

```
class ParentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = ('var1', 'var2')


class ChildForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ('var1', 'var3', 'var4', 'var5', 'var6')


ParentFormSet = forms.inlineformset_factory(
    Parent,
    Child,
    form=ParentForm,
    fields=('var1', 'var3', 'var4', 'var5', 'var6'),
    extra=1,
    can_delete=False,
    can_order=False
)
```

views.py

```
class CreateSetView(CreateView):
    template_name = "create_set_view.html"
    model = Parent
    form_class = ParentForm
    success_url = 'parent_list/'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        form_set = ParentFormSet()
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form, form_set=form_set))

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        form_set = ParentFormSet(self.request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and form_set.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form, form_set)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, form_set)

    def form_valid(self, form, form_set):
        self.object = form.save()
        form_set.instance = self.object
        form_set.save()
        return redirect(self.get_success_url())

    def form_invalid(self, form, form_set):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form, form_set=form_set))
```

create_set_view.html (`form_set.varX` does not work as anticipated)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <br>
        {{ form_set.var3 }}
        <br>
        {{ form_set.var4 }}{{ form_set.var5 }}{{ form_set.var6 }}
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is that formset is a collection of forms (both empty and non empty forms). So, to get the specific fields of the formset you need to do something like this:

```
<br>
{{ form_set.management_form }}
{% for form in form_set.forms %}
    {{ form.var3 }}
    <br>
    {{ form.var4 }}
    {{ form.var5 }}
    {{ form.var6 }}
{% endfor %}
```

For adding multiple forms, you need to use some JavaScript or JQuery. Also, for `var3` to appear only once, I think a proper real-world situation could help us to understand what you are wanting to achieve.

Comment: I want var3 to be a csv upload that would fill out var4, var5, and var6. If there were 3 rows in the csv file, then there would be 3 values for the set var4, var5, and var6. I think I should just make var3 a separate form from var4, var5, and var6. Then on the backend I could populate the other model.